# Programmer's Debugging toolkit pack

Tags: debugging, operating-system, gdb, system

What kind of debugging tools you've been using to debug working binaries? 
Is there are debugging toolkits in addition to GDB?

The only reason is that I'm quite new for system debugging and I've been debugging my system service.
Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend Valgrind [1]. It's quite useful when dealing with memory leaks and segfaults.

The segfaults can be tracked by letting GDB run (without any breakpoint) and check the backtrace ('bt' command), after the crash.

P.S.: I don't remember if Valgrind is avaliable for other systems, but since you asked about alternatives to GDB, I'm assuming you're on a *nix box.

Have a nice debugging.

[1] http://valgrind.org/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Linux systems, one of the most valuable tool is *valgrind*.

I don't really use anything else except for precondition/postcondition check in the code itself (i.e. assertion on methods' input values).